# How can i increase the number of table columns dynamically in itext PdfPTable

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have have a I text pdf table, I want to dynamically increase the columns, and as well as i want to put the column widths for the added columns.

```
table=new PdfPTable(5);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
            table.setWidths(new float[]{0.5f,0.7f,0.7f,0.5f,1.0f});
```

In the above it works fine,
but if increase the table columns like below

```
int size=3;
table=new PdfPTable(5+size);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
            table.setWidths(new float[]{0.5f,0.7f,0.7f,0.5f,1.0f,___});

            cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sl. No.",fontBold));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(cell);
```

I have know that If I don't put any setWidths then also it works like below

```
table=new PdfPTable(5);

            cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sl. No.",fontBold));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(cell);
```

but it automatically taking the paper width, for that colspan and rowspan not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Use a method like this so that you can enter the cell widths as a float array, set the position where to create the table and and also the total width of the entire table.

```
 public void AddTable(float[] cellWidths, int x, int y, float totalWidth, int page)
        {
            table = new Table(cellWidths);
            table.SetWidth(totalWidth);
            table.SetFixedPosition(page, x, y, totalWidth);
        }
```